# Cannot connect to VM via Azure Lab Services Virtual Machine Pool. RDP does not download

Tags: azure-lab-services

The connect icon in Azure Lab Services --> Virtual Machine Pool does not download the RDP file to connect to VM

Answer (score 0):

are you still seeing this issue? I was not able to reproduce this bug. Please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

No this error seems to be fixed. It was only there for a day.